# how do I dump the in-memory core-data store to a NSData object?

Tags: ios, core-data

I think the title is clear enough. how do I dump the in-memory core-data store to a NSData object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your heading, but is this what you are looking for :

```
- (NSPersistentStore *)migratePersistentStore:(NSPersistentStore *)store   
                                        toURL:(NSURL *)URL 
                                      options:(NSDictionary *)options 
                                     withType:(NSString *)storeType 
                                        error:(NSError **)error
```

[Reference in NSPersistentStoreCoordinator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html)
With that you can change the format of your store to `NSSQLiteStoreType` or `NSBinaryStoreType` That way you would be able to "persist" it.
I assume that is the reason why you want an NSData.